# Dynamic SQL issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

I have a dynamic SQL which sits inside a stored procedure, but when I run the stored procedure I am not seeing any results. It is very odd, because when I strip out the SQL from the string, and just run it as an SQL Query I do get back results. I have tried getting the Dynamic SQL to print out so I could see what is going on, but this isn't working either. Therefore, I am at a loss to see what I am doing wrong, and would kindly ask if anyone can see what is wrong. Below is the query:

```
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'Select Production_Site, CSN, Target, Action, Fail '
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'From syn_products prod, '
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + '(select Production_Site, CSN, SUM([Target]) AS Target,SUM([Action]) AS Action,SUM([Fail]) AS Fail '
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' from '
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' ( '
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' select Production_Site, value, Period, YEAR, week, CSN '
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' from t_Pqe_Grocery '
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' unpivot ( '
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' value '
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' for col in (Grocery_Packaging_And_Coding, Grocery_Measurable, '
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' Grocery_Appearance, Grocery_Aroma, '
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' Grocery_Flavour, Grocery_Texture)) unp '
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' ) src '
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' pivot '
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' ( '
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' count(value) '
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' for value in ([Target], [Action], [Fail]) '
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' ) piv '
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' where Production_Site IN ( ''' + @Site + ''') AND YEAR BETWEEN ' + CONVERT(varchar(50),CONVERT(BIGINT,@ToYear))+ 'AND '+ CONVERT(varchar(50),CONVERT(BIGINT,@FromYear))+ 'AND Period BETWEEN ' + CONVERT(varchar(50),CONVERT(BIGINT,@ToPeriod))+ ' AND '+ CONVERT(varchar(50),CONVERT(BIGINT,@FromPeriod))+ 'AND Week BETWEEN ' + CONVERT(varchar(50),CONVERT(BIGINT,@ToWeek))+ ' AND '+CONVERT(varchar(50),CONVERT(BIGINT,@FromWeek))+ ' GROUP BY Production_Site CSN'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' ) pit'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' WHERE prod.pProductCode = pit.CSN AND prod.pPowerBrand = ''POW'''
EXECUTE(@SQL)
```

Comment: Before your `EXECUTE(@SQL)`, use either `print @sql` or `select @sql` to see what the query looks like, then try running that query

Comment: As I said in my note - I did that and it showed nothing to me

Comment: It shows you nothing from the stored procedure?  If so, then try running it outside of the stored proc, just open a new query window and execute only this part to get the query string

Comment: And do you get any errors? Can you see the query string?  If you can see the string, edit your OP and post the query that you are getting.

Comment: I am not getting any error and the print sql is not showing either. I have tried breaking the query up without any restrictions, and that didn't work either

Comment: I have copied the query into a new stored proc and executed with exec temp_proc "'SiteA','SiteB'",2012,11,48,2012,11,48 All it gave me back was command completed successfully. This should have given me back one row

Comment: Probably a NULL string concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes formatting your query in a different way can help find any errors with your query. You were missing some spaces in your query string:

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
declare @Site varchar(10) = 'testSite'
declare @ToYear int = 2010
declare @FromYear int = 2012
declare @ToPeriod int = 45
declare @FromPeriod int = 56
declare @ToWeek int = 10
declare @FromWeek  int = 1

SET @SQL =
 'Select Production_Site, CSN, Target, Action, Fail 
  From syn_products prod
  inner join 
  (
    select Production_Site, CSN, SUM([Target]) AS Target,SUM([Action]) AS Action,SUM([Fail]) AS Fail 
    from 
    ( 
      select Production_Site, value, Period, YEAR, week, CSN 
      from t_Pqe_Grocery 
      unpivot 
      ( 
        value 
        for col in (Grocery_Packaging_And_Coding, 
                    Grocery_Measurable, Grocery_Appearance, 
                    Grocery_Aroma, Grocery_Flavour, Grocery_Texture)
      ) unp 
    ) src 
    pivot
    ( 
      count(value)
      for value in ([Target], [Action], [Fail])
    ) piv 
    where Production_Site IN ( ''' + @Site + ''') 
      AND YEAR BETWEEN ' + CONVERT(varchar(50),CONVERT(BIGINT,@ToYear))+ ' AND '+ CONVERT(varchar(50),CONVERT(BIGINT,@FromYear))
      + ' AND Period BETWEEN ' + CONVERT(varchar(50),CONVERT(BIGINT,@ToPeriod))+ ' AND '+ CONVERT(varchar(50),CONVERT(BIGINT,@FromPeriod)) 
      + ' AND Week BETWEEN ' + CONVERT(varchar(50),CONVERT(BIGINT,@ToWeek))+ ' AND '+CONVERT(varchar(50),CONVERT(BIGINT,@FromWeek))
    + ' GROUP BY Production_Site CSN
  ) pit
     on prod.pProductCode = pit.CSN 
  where prod.pPowerBrand = ''POW'''

select @sql
```

This is now printing --- See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/6861)  -- I also changed the query to use ANSI join syntax instead of comma separated joins.

Comment: Did you alter it? When I load the fiddle I get no errors -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/6861

Answer (score 0):

These are probably syntax errors:

```
... CONVERT(BIGINT,@ToYear))+ 'AND '+ ...
                               ^--- no space

... @FromYear))+ 'AND Period BETWEEN ...
                  ^---no space

... @FromPeriod))+ 'AND Week BETWEEN
                    ^-- yet again no space
```

Comment: yes, that's the problem. you'll be generating something like `... 2012AND`

Comment: Sorry, mis-understood you. Add spaces still no change

Answer (score 0):

One of your variables is probably `NULL`.  Concatenating a `NULL` value into your string will result in a NULL string.  Both `PRINT` and `EXECUTE` when given `NULL` strings..

First, you need to set the `@SQL` parameter to an empty string or change the first line to set the value instead of concatenating it.  Then, you may need to do some kind of checking to verify the parameters are NOT NULL and, if they are, either remove the criteria, or substitute something else:

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = ''
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ... -- now build the SQL Statement
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' where Production_Site IN ( ''' + ISNULL(@Site, '') + ''' ... -- check for NULLs here

PRINT ISNULL(@SQL, 'NULL) -- this should now print something even if the SQL is NULL
```

Finally, **beware of SQL injection attacks**!  Avoid concatenating parameters into a dynamic SQL statement like this.  Instead, parameterize the dynamic SQL, and pass the parameters along with the EXECUTE statement.